# Isolating http requests of 3rd party components in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I know it's good practice to isolate all the components which use http-requests into angular services to make testing and debugging easier. Right now I'm dealing with the 3rd party library which sends http-requests (lazyLoad in [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki)). Is there a general recipe on how to deal with such libraries, maybe how to wrap their requests so that they all go through `$http`?

Comment: We've used `$resource` successfully to maintain and control all our external requests and responses. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: how exactly? I always thought about `$resource` as of shortcut for REST `$http` queries. In this case it's the fancytree which is executing queries, maybe I can somehow intercept them?

Comment: It seems you can pass a JSON object to the `source` param required by Fancytree, so you can still make all the calls (internal or external) using `$http` or `$resource`. I modified their example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4GjRv/778/ At the moment it's only static, but imagine you grab that from scope or a result.